# Did Tolkien ever address Gandalf's propensity to take risks?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, gandalf, smaug

Gandalf wanted to get rid of Smaug, fearing that Smaug could eventually become an ally and tool of Sauron. But at the time of The Hobbit, Smaug was slumbering in Erebor. Gandalf explicitly discouraged direct confrontation with Smaug, lamenting about the short supply of Heroes. Instead he "encouraged" Thorin & Co. to travel to Erebor with a plan to take back some treasure by making use of a burglar - Bilbo Baggins.

It seems to me that the chance of success for Thorin & Co was very low; some might even say reckless. At the outset of the quest, nobody had any idea of how Smaug might actually be killed, and it seems more likely that the quest would end with the company awakening Smaug, resulting in their immediate death.

Did Tolkien ever address Gandalf's decision to take such a risk?

Comment: Gandalf wasn't just flying by the seat of his pants and winging it; even if he didn't (consciously) know _why_ at the time, he knew he needed Bilbo to join the party.  He didn't always know what he had to do, or possibly he didn't want to acknowledge it (like entering Moria), but he recognized there was a necessity driving things.  It wasn't random, and he _always_ tried to give the best help and counsel he could.

Comment: Why do you say that Gandalf sent Thorin & Co. to reacquire the Arkenstone?

Comment: Gandalf does take enormous risks at times, but this is not necessarily indicative of a 'character flaw'. I have edited the question to reflect this and will now vote to reopen.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Wasn't that the "mission" in the movie version? (Which is one of the very, very, few things I thought the movie did well; IIRC, the idea was for Thorin to reclaim the Arkenstone in order to put forth his claim to rule all the Dwarves. Not in the book, but a non-ridiculous deviation compared to some of the movie-only additions.)

Answer (score 1):

"It seems to me that the chance of success for Thorin & Co is almost nothing." You are ignoring the foresight that Gandalf shows at multiple times in the novel. The foresight is neither clear nor certain, but he clearly is wise enough to heed it when it comes. (Remember, Gandalf, a Maiar, was a being who lived before the creation of Arda and took part in the Song of Ainur which Eru made real as the world. While his memory of the Song was hindered by his embodiment as an old man, it was not erased.)

I'll grant that for you or me to act as he did would be foolhardy.